# If I'm attacked while building something, will I have to restart the process?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I'm building something in clash of clans which takes 8 hours to be completed. If I get attacked, do I have to start it all over again?

Answer (score 4):

From [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/93965/what-happens-when-i-get-attacked-by-another-player):

- Your buildings are not actually destroyed, even when the opponent "destroys" them.

So your building will not be destroyed and continued building.

Answer (score 0):

The fact about clash of clans is that, your village is actually at a magical place where everything is repaired with time, automatically, so even if u r attacked the buildings take few seconds to repair themselves when u open ur account back.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can lose when you are attacked is resources and trophies