# If someone attacks me and destroys my Laboratory, will the current upgrade stop working?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I was upgrading my pekka to level 3.
It was meant to finish after 2 days 3 hours.
Someone raided and destroyed my barracks and laboratory.

**Will the upgrade of my troop finish?**

Comment: So to clear up, you're upgrading your Pekka to level 3 and the upgrade will finish in about 2 days and 3 hours? Can't understand the rest of the question mate sorry

Comment: Please, rephrase your question, it's really confusing.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you remember the times wrong.

Comment: Apart from loosing loot nothing will change, everything will continue to work as normal.

Answer (score 3):

I am sure that's not the case. If your buildings get destroyed they will just keep working like usual. Building time isn't affected. Maybe you had the times wrong? I've had that happen to me.

For a full list of what happens if your base gets destroyed, check this question out:

[What happens when I get attacked by another player?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/93965/what-happens-when-i-get-attacked-by-another-player)